# Best Way to Restart 2 Node SQL Cluster To Perform Windows Updates?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

So I have a 2 node MS SQL Server cluster, using AlwaysOn, on Windows 2012 r2.  SQL1 is the primary.  SQL2 is the secondary.  I want to restart both servers today to perform windows updates which will require a restart.  I can tolerate downtime to do this.  What's the best way?  In particular, I'm concerned about Microsoft SQL Server freaking out and making SQL2 the primary while #1 is rebooting, and then going back to making #1 the primary again.   Should I just right click the entire cluster first and choose "shut down" so no rollover will occur? Or would I do that by right clicking a node and choosing "stop cluster service"?  Both sound similar to me.  Or should I right click each node and choose "pause" and drain each separately (and in what order)?  It seems there are multiple ways.  I just want to make this simple, do the windows updates, restart the servers (one at a time or both at a time), and still have SQL1 as primary and SQL2 as secondary.  What's the best way?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using availability groups you can follow the [Rolling Upgrade and Update Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178483.aspx).

If they are plain Failover Clustered Instances then you can follow the [Rolling Update Guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/958734) for that.